# NativeScript 'tns run android' throws unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl-certificate, nativescript

My computer is behind a proxy. I have just add keystore for jcenter.bintray.com.

> "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -import -trustcacerts -alias C:\cer\p7b -file C:\cer\p7b\jcenter.cer -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts

When i run 'tns run android' , it throws errors:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download uast.jar (com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.0.1)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.0.1/uast-26.0.1.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.0.1/uast-26.0.1.jar'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>      ....

Comment: i'm sorry. this is the problem with build.grade. It does not regard proxy and java keystore